# Compound conditions using while loop in C.

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

The program is ignoring Stop when amt is 0 until after 10 numbers have been entered. The program also doesn't stop after 10 numbers have been entered. Where is my error?

```
main() {
int amt;
int tot = 0; /* running total */
int i = 0;   /* counts number of times in loop */
while (amt!=0 || i < 10)
    {
     printf("Enter a number (enter 0 to stop): ");
     scanf("%d", &amt);
     tot = tot + amt;
     i++;
    }
printf("The sum of those %d number is %d.\n", i, tot);

}
```

Comment: Please just compile your code with all warnings switched on before you post here. Any decent compiler would have told you something like "use of unitialized value `amt`.. " and that the prototype of `main` is different.

Comment: @JensGustedt - you should have added that as an answer.  It is amazing that no one even thinks that a compiler warning might actually be telling you that something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @D.Shawley, no, no, I don't want SO to be overloaded with trivialities. I would merely close the question, this isn't of any use for others.

Comment: I'm using an SSH connection to my school and using the compiler in the server; when I compiled the program no errors came up. 
How can i use a better compiler while also using vim as an editor in windows 7?

Comment: @jrasa, your compiler probably has a command line switch or similar to increase its warning level. For gcc this is `-Wall`, for example. Your  teachers should have told you. And I think on windows there are also several modern compilers available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is happening before `amt` is assigned. Thus its results are undefined. This test should be moved to the end of the iteration, i.e. a `do/while`. Whilst you could assign `amt` to some non-zero value this feels slightly untidy to me.

And surely you mean to use logical AND rather than logical OR? You only want to continue iterating if both `amt` is non-zero AND `i<10`.

Of course, if you did move the test to the end of the iteration then you would have to account for the fact that `i` had been incremented inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In order to stop after 10 numbers or amt=0 (whichever first is met) you'll have to change the loop condition to `while (amt!=0 && i < 10)`

Comment: Thank you. This was the correct answer. The program wasn't giving any undefined behaviour -- it just wasn't following the conditions properly.

Comment: @jrasa The program does have undefined behaviour. It's as plain as can be. This answer is most certainly not the full story. If `amt` happens to be zero when you hit the test the first time, you will no longer enter the loop once you have change to using `&&`. In your version of the program the undefined behaviour is benign because the test always evaluates to true the first time round since i<10 holds.

Comment: @jrasa I totally agree with the comment above - the condition is not the only problem, despite being significant for your input data. If you only change the condition, other mentioned factors may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
int amt;
```

Since you do not initialize it. It has some random value and that causes the Undefined Behavior in your program.
You should always initialize local variables with values.